How can I scale down Android Studio?
I just started Android Studio, but everything is scaled very large.
My system info:

johannes@Lenovov15ada
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Host: 82C7 Lenovo V15-ADA
Kernel: 6.8.9-zen1-2-zen
Uptime: 7 mins
Shell: bash 5.2.26
Resolution: 1920x1080
CPU: AMD 3020e with Radeon Graphics (2
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Rade
Memory: 3733MiB / 13850MiB


I have already tried to reinstall it (by deleting the config files I could find), but it doesn't change anything. I have already looked in the Setting, but I couldn't find anything. I have tried to run it as root and the scale was normal, but I don't want to always use it as root. (There must be a problem with the config files of my user)

What desktop system do you use (Gnome, KDE, ..)? Have you tried to just get past the setup wizard? That is just the part where Android SDK is loaded and installed. May be the main program scales correctly.
